# Default route action not working after upgrade to ASP.NET Core MVC 2.2

Tags: asp.net-core, asp.net-core-mvc

After updating my app from asp.net core 2.1 to 2.2 it seems that default route action is not working for controllers that live in a separate class library.

For example I have a default route like this:

```
routes.MapRoute(
            name: "default",
            template: "{controller}/{action}"
            ,defaults: new { controller = "Home", action = "index" }
            );
```

and in my class library I have a controller SiteAdminController which has an Index action method.

When I visit the url /siteadmin I get the HomeController index and not the index action of the SiteAdminController

if I use /siteadmin/index then it works

How can I make it work without requiring the index action to be explicitly in the url? It worked fine in 2.1

Comment: Are you using the 2.2 compatibility level? `.AddMvc().SetCompatibilityVersion(CompatibilityVersion.Version_2_2)`? or the old 2_1 compatibility? (it determines if endpoint routing is used or the mvc router middleware). Can also be disabled separately via `MvcOption`'s `EnableEndpointRouting` property

Comment: yes 2.2 compatibility and in  process hosting

Comment: changing to 2.1 compatibility does solve the problem, but I want it to work with 2.2 compatibility

Comment: having trouble trying to replicate this issue in a new solution, can't figure out what is different in my main solution that could be causing this.

Comment: strangely I can't seem to reproduce this in other solutions than the main dev solution for cloudscribe core. If anyone wants to try to help figure it out the repo is here:https://github.com/cloudscribe/cloudscribe Note that even new projects created with our project template and using our nugets, when upgraded to netcoreapp2.2 work just fine. At the moment I'm stumped why this problem happens.

Comment: Is the class controller in the other solutions in a class library too? Try adding the class library via application part: Or maybe its just some case sensitivity issue with the new routing?

Comment: yes works fine with controllers in class libraries in other solutions. and even the class libraries in the problem solution when consumed as nugets work fine in other solutions. I should mention also that the class libraries reference 2.1 aspnet core libs even though the the main app references 2.2. But that doesn't seem to be a factor as I tried replicating that factor in other solutions but the issue doesn't happen

Comment: also I've tried different casing in the route declaration and no change. I'm forcing lower case routes.

Answer (score -1):

Have you tried setting the defaults in the template?

```
app.UseMvc(routes =>
        {
            routes.MapRoute(
              name: "default", 
              template: "{controller=Home}/{action=Index}");
        }
);
```

This worked for me in Core 2.2

Comment: I meant literally in the template, not as "defaults: new controller = .." The latter doesn't work if I try it. Defining it in the template does.